# Is it possible to use GTK+ in Android?

Tags: android, gtk

Is it possible to use GTK+ library with Android?

Comment: GTK is open source. You're welcome to port it.

Comment: Sweet!  Yaks are so beautiful when they're shaved!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try [GTKAndroid](https://github.com/eugals/GTKAndroid).

It still has many limitations at the moment when I'm writing this comment,
but you should be able to run some simple forms with this already.

Comment: Great resource, but according to the creator, it "The current code base DOESN'T WORK on the modern NDK versions." right now. It currently has links to [its forks](https://github.com/eugals/GTKAndroid/network/members) that might provide better functionality.

Answer (score 10):

Nothing is impossible. First of all, GTK library need to be coss-compiled. After that, the compiled library need to be deployed to android.

Answer (score 3):

Even JAVA can run native code, there should be a way, http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/1.6_r1/index.html

Comment: no, I think `java` is more native than `c` in Android?

Comment: @FelixXu how native is it, just because the OS has a JVM built-in doesn't mean it is "closer to the metal" than C, does it?
I guess that depends on the definition of "native".

Answer (score 2):

You can run GTK applications on Android through the broadway backend.