# How can we use Abstract Widget Toolkit(AWT)/Swing on Android's Jvdroid IDE

Tags: java, android, awt

I am using the jvdroid IDE on android, which largely compiles and executes Java code accurately. However, I would like to create Java applications that make use of a graphical user interface (GUI) using this IDE. How is it possible to use swing or awt to accomplish this?

So far, I have tried using AWT, using the following code:

```
import java.awt.* ;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Frame f = new Frame() ;

        f.setVisible(true) ;

    }

}
```

Upon saving and executing, I get the following output :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException:
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
        at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at Main.main(Main.java:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Swing produces the same error as your awt compile, *expectedly*:

```
~/Git/java $ java -cp ./swingx-1.6.jar:. HelloWorldSwing
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.HeadlessException:
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
        at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at HelloWorldSwing.createAndShowGUI(HelloWorldSwing.java:11)
        at HelloWorldSwing$1.run(HelloWorldSwing.java:28)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
~/Git/java $
```

Then, swt produces its own kind of error. But largely the swt error suggests that [graphical display (gimp toolkit or gtk)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964655/is-it-possible-to-use-gtk-in-android) capabilities are *NOT* available in [java for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344654/how-to-add-java-awt-image-package-in-android#:%7E:text=The%20Java%20AWT%20classes%20contain%20native%20code%2C%20so,above%2C%20Android%20has%20its%20own%20graphics%20libraries%20%28android.graphics%29.):

```
~/Git/Java $ javac -cp ./swt2.jar:. HelloWorldSWT.java
~/Git/Java $ java -cp ./swt2.jar:. HelloWorldSWT
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons:
        no swt-gtk-4946r21 in java.library.path: [/data/data/ru.iiec.jvdroid/files/lib/server, /data/data/ru.iiec.jvdroid/files/lib, /data/data/ru.iiec.jvdroid/files/../lib, /data/user/0/ru.iiec.jvdroid/files/lib, /data/user/0/ru.iiec.jvdroid/files/lib/jli, /data/user/0/ru.iiec.jvdroid/files/lib/server, /usr/java/packages/lib, /lib, /usr/lib]
        no swt-gtk in java.library.path: [/data/data/ru.iiec.jvdroid/files/lib/server, /data/data/ru.iiec.jvdroid/files/lib, /data/data/ru.iiec.jvdroid/files/../lib, /data/user/0/ru.iiec.jvdroid/files/lib, /data/user/0/ru.iiec.jvdroid/files/lib/jli, /data/user/0/ru.iiec.jvdroid/files/lib/server, /usr/java/packages/lib, /lib, /usr/lib]
        no swt in java.library.path: [/data/data/ru.iiec.jvdroid/files/lib/server, /data/data/ru.iiec.jvdroid/files/lib, /data/data/ru.iiec.jvdroid/files/../lib, /data/user/0/ru.iiec.jvdroid/files/lib, /data/user/0/ru.iiec.jvdroid/files/lib/jli, /data/user/0/ru.iiec.jvdroid/files/lib/server, /usr/java/packages/lib, /lib, /usr/lib]
        Can't load library: /data/user/0/ru.iiec.jvdroid/app_HOME/.swt/lib/linux/aarch64/libswt-gtk-4946r21.so
        Can't load library: /data/user/0/ru.iiec.jvdroid/app_HOME/.swt/lib/linux/aarch64/libswt-gtk.so
        Can't load library: /data/user/0/ru.iiec.jvdroid/app_HOME/.swt/lib/linux/aarch64/libswt.so
        /data/data/ru.iiec.jvdroid/app_HOME/.swt/lib/linux/aarch64/libswt-gtk-4946r21.so: dlopen failed: library "libc.so.6" not found

        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:348)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:257)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:19)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:209)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:155)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:165)
        at HelloWorldSWT.main(HelloWorldSWT.java:6)
~/Git/Java $
```